# How to find what is preventing an implicit conversion (pimp class)?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a code which uses pimped jme Quaternion math. The math extension (for Java jMonkeyEngine Quaternion) looks like this:

```
object Operators {
  implicit class QuaternionMath(val a: Quaternion) extends AnyVal {
    def * (b: Quaternion) = a mult b
    //def * (b: Float) = a mult b
  }
}
```

The code using the math looks like this:

```
import Operators._
```

... and later in a function:

```
def compute(q1: Quaternion, q2: Quaternion) = {
  q1 * q2
}
```

Now after adding some more code which seems not related, I get a syntax error:

> Error:(477, 10) value * is not a member of com.jme3.math.Quaternion

To fix the error I need to repeat the import right before the computation, either as a wildcard again, or a specific one:

```
import Operators.QuaternionMath

import Operators._
```

I have no idea what can be hiding the `QuaternionMath` implicit conversion. Is there some way how to check that, some tool, or some compiler switches?

Comment: What's the "code which seems unrelated"?  What's the file/package structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `QuaternionMath` really is in scope, you should be able to write

```
val m: location.of.Operators.QuaternionMath = QuaternionMath(q1)
m.*(c2)
```

If the first line fails, it will be telling either that

- value `QuaternionMath` is not found. It's really not in scope
- that you can't call it that way, and then you have shadowed it by something else called `QuaternionMath`. In this case you could in an IDE just jump to the source of that shadowing symbol.
- that `QuaternionMath` is not a member of `Operators` (my guess here). Then `Operators` is not *that* object that you imagine but another one with the same name. Again in the IDE, just select the `Operators` bit of `import Operators._` and look up the source (Ctrl-B in IntelliJ) to verify you are doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: Great. It showed my the QuaternionMath is ambiguous, because some of the other code which was imported was doing this: implicit def QuaternionMath(a: Quaternion): QuaternionMath = Operators.QuaternionMath(a)

Comment: I cannot write Operators.QuaterionMath, as Operators is not imported, only Operators._ - I have fixed that, the rest of the advice and analysis seems really good.

Comment: Ok, although your edit `val m: Operators.QuaternionMath` -> `val m: QuaternionMath` hides my point - that you could have different equally named `QuaternionMath`. I'll undo that edit and fully qualify `Operators` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA for Scala then try checking possible implicit conversions by selecting an expression and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> for Mac), check [this tutorial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Implicit+Conversions).

For Scala IDE there is [implicit conversion highlighting](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/typingviewing/implicit-highlighting/index.html).

Comment: Nice. When pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Q` on `q1` I am offered two different implicit conversions, and this shows the ambiguity.